# assign unique ID to django comments form

Tags: django, jquery, django-templates

I am building a similar wall feature to what facebook has, comments etc.

I am making use of django's comments framework and jquery to post and get on success, and I am looking at a way of extracting the the hidden `id_object_pk`'s value and using that also as the forms id

Your normal form is rendered in the following way.

```
<form action="/comments/post/" method="post" class="comment-form" id="">
    <input type="hidden" name="content_type" value="wall.post" id="id_content_type" />
    <input type="hidden" name="object_pk" value="76" id="id_object_pk" />
    <input type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="1283848690" id="id_timestamp" />
    <input type="hidden" name="security_hash" value="ccf0e2f3cbbd57cb043df3f304a8dd50a74e972b" id="id_security_hash" />
```

How can I access those details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to sort this out by making use of the .each function in jQuery.

```
$('.comment-form').each(function(){
    var element = $(this).find('#id_object_pk').val();
    $(this).attr('id', element);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My jQuery fu is very weak, so take this answer with a pinch of salt. There are probably better ways to do this.

First, you need to find the input with the comment id.

```
var element = $('#id_object_pk');
```

Next, extract the comment id itself. That would be the `value` attribute of the input element.

```
var comment_id = element.attr('value');
```

Finally update your form's id attribute and set it to `comment_id`.

```
var form = $('.comment-form');
form.attr('id', comment_id);
```

Comment: yeah that makes sense, I'll try it out and see. Although I know you can remove the second line. and make the first var element = $('#id_object_pk').val();

Comment: that does work, however based on the fact that I have more than one form, all the form IDS end up being the same i.e. 77 or so.

Comment: That is because all your forms share the same style class. _If_ you use different, non-empty ID for each of your forms initially then you can use that ID to select and _replace_ as appropriate.